# How to deserialize geoJon input to locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry

Tags: geojson, java, jts-topology-suite

I have following input to a Spring ReST endpoint:

```
{
    "featureType": "feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          65.0390625,
          62.91523303947614
        ]
      }
}
```

I am trying to map it to a custom class I have defined as:

```
public class Feature   {
  @JsonProperty("featureType")
  private String featureType = null;

  @JsonProperty("geometry")
  private Geometry geometry = null;
}
```

Geometry is org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry.

I have following pom dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphhopper.external</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jts</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

And I have configured JtsModule as bean:

```
   @Bean
   public JtsModule jtsModule()
   {
      return new JtsModule();
   }
```

But I get error:

```
"Type definition error: [simple type, class org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry` (no Creators, like default construct, exist)
```

I am not able to get what part I am missing here.

Comment: This is better asked (and has been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45713934/jackson-deserialize-geojson-point-in-spring-boot/62259822#62259822)) on Stackoverflow